# JFrame (being fullscreened) background color not changing

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jframe

im using

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
```

to set the background of a JFrame to the color pink. this JFrame is being fullscreened using a GraphicsDevice. the color of the background is not changing. any help?

fullscreen code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
     DisplayMode dMode = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
     GameMain game = new GameMain();
     game.run(dMode);

 }

 public void run(DisplayMode dMode) {
     getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
     setForeground(Color.WHITE);
     setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

     Screen s = new Screen();
     try {
         s.setFullScreen(dMode, this);
         try {
             Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch(Exception e) { }
     } finally {
         s.restoreScreen();
     }
```

### }

```
 public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dMode, JFrame window) {
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    gDevice.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    if(dMode != null && gDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
        try {
            gDevice.setDisplayMode(dMode);
        } catch(Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we also get the code you used to make the frame full screen, please :D

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (like posted in the answer of @MadProgrammer - only short of imports).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me...

```
public class TestFullScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                FullFrame frame = new FullFrame();
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);

                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

                gs[0].setFullScreenWindow(frame);

            }
        });

    }

    public static class FullFrame extends JFrame {

        public FullFrame() {
            super();

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I even set moved the `setBackground` call after the `setFullScreenWindow` call.

Make sure you don't have anything on the content pane that might be taking up the full space and that the content pane hasn't been changed.

Comment: this unfortunately is not working for me. i dont believe there is anything "inside" the JFrame, its just the JFrame itself with some text in it using the paint method ( g.drawString("string",int,int); )

Comment: *this unfortunately is not working for me* - what the example? What JVM and under what OS are you running?

Comment: that is the paint method, g is the Graphics parameter. and what i mean by "its not working for me" is that its not changing the background color, its doing stuff, but its just a black screen

Comment: Okay, did you try the example I wrote, did that work?  If it did, then it's a problem with your code and I'm looking at that `paint` method.  If not, then it's a potential bug. You could try commenting out you custom `paint` method and see if that has any effect. Remember, the content pane sits ontop of the frame so unless you respect the paint chain properly, you will get weird results.  Does it work in normal windowed mode?

Comment: yes your example works. when i comment out my paint method, the background color changes... i dont understand why that would make a difference

Comment: And the `paint` method to the question.  Painting in top level containers (like the `JFrame`) is always a bad idea, there is more going on then meets the eye and they're not double buffered. Better to use a custom component and override `paintComponent`

Comment: ic.. im not sure how this custom component is supposed to work. i jsut made a class that extends Component and it has the method paintComponent(Graphics g) with the code i originally had for the paint method. how am i supposed to invoke the new paintComponent(g) method?

Comment: You don't.  That's the responsibility of the repaint manager. You can ask for a paint cycle via the `repaint` method of the component (personally, I'd just a Swing component, like `JPanel`, they're double buffered). Simply add the custom component to your frame

Comment: i think this project im working on is beyond my capabilities at the moment. im basically following an outdated tutorial on how to do game stuff. thanks for your help